# Getting file paths outside the folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to acces files outside my main.js folder,below is my folder structure:

```
ent
 src
   ep
    main.js
 config
   abc.js
   xyz.js
```

I have tried doing `var config_src = __dirname+"/../../config"` it works fine, but not acceptable bt my TL.What is the other way to get the path of congig folder?

Comment: Can you explain what a TL is?

Answer (score 4):

`__dirname` returns your working (project) directory. then you have out from that folder. suppose your folder structure and using `sonfig_src` in app.js :

```
somefoledr
   |___somefolder1
   |___somefolder2
          |__config
yourProject
   |___ app.js
```

One more thing you did not used `const path = require('path')` package.

Now your code should look like this :

```
const path = require('path')
const config_src = path.resolve(__dirname, "/../somefoledr/somefoledr2/config")
```

But it can be harmful when you will deploy it on server, it could create path problem !

Comment: I want to completely remeove the usage of "../" and fetch the absolute path of config folder

Comment: I tried a lot but using varoius ways, bt could get path till the src folder, how can i fetch the path for config without usage of "../"

Comment: checkout this link, m sure you will find you solution here : https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: but setting path this way will not work when the project is deployed. The path may not be the sane

Comment: I tried using require('app-root-path') which gives me the path till src directory, but again am stuck how to navigate till config.I dont want to use "../" for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

Use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

```
const path = require('path')
const config_src = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../config")
```